# In C++ how do you access a multidimensional Array in ClassA, from ClassB?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop

"ClassA.h"

```
class ClassA {
public:
classArray[10][5];

void loadArray(){
//loads ints into array
}
};
```

"ClassB.h"

```
class classB {
void outputArray(){
ClassA classA;
cout << classA.classArray[1][1];
}

};
```

Whenever I print the array[1][1], it outputs 0 to console. Despite having loaded 7020 into it. In the main both functions are called.

Comment: You need to call `loadArray` like `classA.loadArray()` before printing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
ClassA classA;
cout << classA.classArray[1][1];
```

you invoke *Undefined Behavior* (UB), since the array of `classA` is used **uninitialized**. First, load the ints to it, and the print it, so you probably need to do this instead:

```
ClassA classA;                       // create an object
classA.loadArray();                  // fill the array of the object
cout << classA.classArray[1][1];     // print a specific element
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a newline initialized `ClassA` instance, and haven't called `loadArray` on it. Either call it explicitly:

```
ClassA classA;
classA.loadArray(); // Here
cout << classA.classArray[1][1];
```

Or, if possible, consider moving this logic to `ClassA`'s constructor.